# AdvertisingIdClient isLimitAdTrackingEnabled true but advertisement id is returned just fine

Tags: android, google-advertising-id

If anyone knows why opting out of ads personalization has no effect on what is returned by AdvertisingIdClient, namely `AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context).getId()` - assuming target sdk 31 is in use and device is also android 12 (but emulator) - please share your knowledge.

I can clearly see the value of `AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context).isLimitAdTrackingEnabled())` is changed based on what user picks inside Ads settings of the device, but advertisement id remains the same (I was expecting all-zeroes or at least different id).

Comment: Seems like a bug, at least in docs. Reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280294734